# Force IE to re-download text file on load

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

My JavaScript has an function that goes off `onload` that takes a .txt file and creates an array from it. The page works fine in Chrome, but doesn't update in IE -- IE seems to cache the .txt file and re-create the array from the cache, ignoring any updates made to the .txt. Is there any way to force IE to re-download the .txt before creating the array so that the user isn't working with an outdated version of the information?

**edit:** Code!! (changed the file pathname, all else is the same)

```
function createArray() {
    var txtFile = new XMLHttpRequest();
    txtFile.open("GET", "http://PATHNAME/names.txt", true);
    txtFile.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (txtFile.readyState === 4) {
            if (txtFile.status === 200 || txtFile.status === 0) {
                nameArray = txtFile.responseText.split("\n");
            }
        }
    };
    txtFile.send(null);
}
```

Furthermore, the file is stored on the server, in the same folder as the page that the data displays on, which is one level above the JavaScripts folder. So the directories look like:

```
page.html
names.txt
SCRIPTS FOLDER
    array.js
```

Comment: Can you post your code please? Where is the `.txt` file located? Server-side or client-side?

Comment: Thanks for the comment! I've edited the post with the relevant portion of the code (the one that actually calls for the file and creates the array); if I need to post the rest of the code, I suppose I will. :) Also edited it with my directory structure, which shows that the .txt file is server-side.

Comment: Get requess cache. add a cache breaker to the querystring.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get requests cache, force it to fetch a new file by changing the url.

```
txtFile.open("GET", "http://PATHNAME/names.txt?ts=" + new Date().getTime(), true);
```

Comment: Works perfectly!! Thanks for the quick response. Looks like it's all functioning exactly as it should. :)